# Adding the sum of variable to itself

Tags: javascript

I have something like `var num = 10;` and I'm trying to get the sum of this number added to itself on a click function.

So it will be `10`; then on click: `20`; and on another click: `30`; and `40`; etc...

Using `++` gives me `11`, `12`, ... and adding the var to itself is `10`, `20`, `40`, `80`,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the variable to itself without storing its original value somewhere, you can't keep adding that value because it has been forgotten.

```
let x = 10;
let originalX = x;
x += originalX; // 20
x += originalX; // 30
x += originalX; // 40
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2) aka `+=`:

```js
var display = document.querySelector('#txtDisplay');
var btn = document.querySelector('#btnIncrement');

let i = 10;
display.setAttribute('value', i);

//calling will increase the value of i by whatever is passed to the outer most function (in this case, the original value of i)
const increment = (function(amount) {
  return function() {
    i += amount;
  }
}(i));

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  increment();
  display.setAttribute('value', i);
});
```

```html
<label>Current value:
  <input id="txtDisplay" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
</label>
<input id="btnIncrement" type="button" value="Increment" />
```

Comment: You aren't adding the number to itself, you've hard-coded the number 10 into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Addition Assignment` operator `+=`

```js
var num = 10,
 org_num = num;
document.getElementById('inc').addEventListener('click', function() {
 num += org_num;
 console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<button id="inc">Increment</button>
```

Comment: You're not adding the number to itself, you've hard-coded 10 as the increment.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **Closures**.

```js
var increment = (() => {
 var firstValue, currentValue;
 firstValue = currentValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('myValue').innerHTML);
 return function(ev) {
    currentValue += firstValue;
    document.getElementById('myValue').innerHTML = currentValue;
 }
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="increment()">Add my first value.</button>
<p id='myValue'>10</p>
```